# React Redux: How to pass specific object prop from store to child component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have an array of objects in my store and a page that lists all of the items in the store. I'd like to have a component that lists information from just one of those individual items. But I don't understand how to pass that individual item's object from the store to a component.

**Router.js:**

```
<Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
    <IndexRoute component={EventListContainer} />
    <Route path=":eventID" component={EventProfileContainer} />
</Route>
```

So, the root page is fine and lists all of the event items in the store. I'd like to use the `:eventID` route to list the individual event items.

**EventProfileContainer.js:**

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const EventProfileContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <EventProfile {...this.props.event} />
    );
  } 
});

const mapStateToProps = function(store, ownProps) {
  return {
    event: _.find(store, 'id', ownProps.params.eventID)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EventProfileContainer);
```

I think the important part here is the `mapStateToProps` function. I think I should be selecting the individual object from the store with this part: `event: _.find(store, 'id', ownProps.params.eventID)` (using lodash _.find()). But maybe I'm missing something?

**EventProfile.js:**

```
export default function(props) {
  return (
    <div className="event-profile">
      <img src={props.image} />
      <div className="details">
        <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        <p>{props.description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Something is being passed to `EventProfile.js` but the page is coming up blank. Name, id, image and description are blank. The object in the store looks like this:

```
name: 'name of the event',
id: '2342343'
description: 'description of the event'
image: 'http://whatever.com/whatever.jpg'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [the signature of `_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) — it expects a predicate, not an attribute name and a value. Try something like this:

```
event: _.find(store, (e) => e.id == ownProps.eventID)
```

(as an aside, calling the first parameter of your `mapStateToProps` function `store` is a bit confusing, as it is not the store that is passed to the function, but the state, that is, `store.getState()`)

Here is a minimal running example:

```js
var store = Redux.createStore(
  (state) => state, {
    events: [
      {name: "event name here", id: "12345", description: "wat"},
      {name: "another event", id: "42", description: "nope"},
    ],
  }
);

function EventProfile(props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.event.name} ({props.event.id})</p>
  );
}
EventProfile = ReactRedux.connect((state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    event: _.find(state.events, (e) => e.id == ownProps.eventID),
  }
})(EventProfile);

ReactDOM.render(
  <EventProfile eventID="42" store={store}/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```